# Move mouse cursor to second monitor using pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I started using `pyautogui` about an hour ago. Very nice that python supports GUI automation. I'm having one problem though. I use two screens and it appears that the wrapper is unable to move my cursor to my secondary monitor. For instance:

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(2759,769)
>>> pyautogui.position()
 (1919, 769)
```

As you can see the cursor is still within my first screen.

How do I force pyautogui to move to my second screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nevermind, I have found the answer from a [github post](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/162).

It appears that moving the cursor to a second monitor can be accomplished using

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(2759,769)
```

Sweet!

Comment: pywinauto (a bit different library you tagged in the question) can do the same: `pywinauto.mouse.move((2759, 769))` because it uses `SetCursorPos` internally. But pywinauto is more text oriented vs. image/coordinates oriented PyAutoGUI.

Comment: use `cursor = ctypes.wintypes.POINT()` and 
`ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(cursor))` to get correct position on multiple monitors

Comment: Do you know how to do this for a mac?