# Clicking a save prompt from a webpage using Python

Tags: python, automation, microsoft-edge

I am trying to click a save prompt on Edge using Python. The file I am saving is an excel file, once I click to export it on Edge, a prompt at the bottom of the page gives me the option to open, save, cancel. How do I get to click save? I tried using `driver.find_element_by_name("Save")` but that didn't work.

Should I find the position of the button instead and then click it that way? How would I find the position of the button? I know how to find the position of the mouse using pyautogui.

EDIT

Here's a visual of what I'm trying to click

[Miscrosoft Edge save bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu9lS.png) I just want to be able to click the "Save" button. It appears at the bottom of the webpage.

EDIT

[Save button picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pot0t.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume you are able to parse the link to the file? would it be a possibility for you to use the link to file and BeautifulSoup or urllib to save the file?

here is an example for using urllib: [Download Files from a Website with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216804/download-files-from-a-website-with-python)

example beautifulsoup & requests: [Download files using requests and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056031/download-files-using-requests-and-beautifulsoup)

regards,

l.

**Edit:**

Thank you for clarification!
I tried it out myself and made it work the following way:

1. Step: Take a Screenshot of the Button you would like to click. It has to be Pixel-Perfect. (Example: [image])
2. Step, alter your code:

   ```
    postion = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pathToScreenshot')
    pyautogui.moveTo(position[0], position[1], 2)
    pyautogui.click()
   ```

Comment: I probably should've mentioned I'm using sharepoint. So there is metadata on a page and what the "Export to Excel" button does is it takes that data and puts it into an excel. The "Export to Excel" button it self doesn't have a link attached to it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I edited my original answer with two steps, which made this work for me.

Comment: I saved the picture under document on my machine and tried saving it as a PNG file then a JPG but I got this error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` . It seems like a took a clear picture, I used snipping tool on my machine. This is what I used as my path `C:\\Users\Documents\Save button for SharePoint\Save.JPG` Then when I leave off the Save.JPG out of the path I get a permission error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\CHI86786\\Documents\\Save button for Sharepoint'` @Leni

Comment: you need to point the path exactly to the screenshot taken. would you mind posting the picture in your original question? also mind to replace all \ with two \\ in your path. maybe the documentation helps:
https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html

Comment: ok yes I pointed it at the path and get that first error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` and yup no problem I added a picture of the save button I am using @Leni

Comment: I got it to work, seems like it wasn't recognizing the image right away so I wrote a while loop.

Comment: Awesome! Congrats!

Comment: Idk if you'd be able to help with this question but it works when Im only using one screen. I have two other screens connected to my laptop and it seems like python can't find the button. I let it run for a good 5 minutes and it seems like the code was stuck in a loop.

Comment: as far as my research is correct pyautogui only supports one screen at the moment. here is an answer concerning moving the mouse to a second screen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647175/move-mouse-cursor-to-second-monitor-using-pyautogui and here is the discussion on the github-project: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/9

Comment: i also read some people recommend using pywinauto for multiple monitors. https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto